# Correctly nest this JS

Tags: javascript

I have this mobile userAgent test for JS and am not quite sure how to nest it properly to extend the test.

Basically now it test if mobile or desktop, what I would like it to do then further is if mobile, check which mobile and do something.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if( /Android|iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    if ( /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        var url = window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        url.show(); 
    }
    elseif 
    if ( /iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        var url = window.location.href = 'http://www.bing.com';
        url.show(); 
    }
  }
    else
  {

  }
</script>
```

I know what is above is wrong, but its as far as I have managed to not work it out.

Comment: Think the `url.show()` is redundant. In Chrome at least just setting the `window.location.href` triggers a page load.

Comment: @TimCroydon Still works in chrome, but yes its old, have not used this in a while, just wanted to fix my apparently really silly mistake before updating it for its intended purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var url="notmobile.html";
  if( /Android|iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    if ( /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        url = 'http://www.google.com';
    }
    else if ( /iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        url = 'http://www.bing.com';
    }
//   url.show(); // some special mobile meaning? - never seen that syntax
    location=url; // this is how I would do it
  }
  else { // not mobile
    // this can be moved out side the ifs with the above location change too
    location = url;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than repeating yourself, you could do something like this:

```
if( /big regex here/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    var agents = {
        "Android":"http://google.com/",
        "iPhone":"http://bing.com/"
    }, i, url;
    for( i in agents) {
        if( new Regexp(i,"i").test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            url = window.location.href = agents[i];
            url.show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```